# JavaMail AuthenticationFailedException IMAP4 access not allowed

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap

I have an authentication error when I try to connect on server. I am using JavaMail ver. 1.6.2 and it gives me this error when I connect to INBOX.
The provider use the STARTTLS for comunication with port 143

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: IMAP4 access not allowed
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:732)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:388)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:267)
    at it.app.test.TestSendEmail.main(TestEmail.java:113)
```

```
        properties.put("mail.store.protocol", "imap");
        
        properties.put("mail.host", "in.alice.it");
        properties.put("mail.user", "user_name@alice.it");
        properties.put("mail.from", "address_mail@alice.it");

        properties.put("mail.imap.host", "in.alice.it");
        properties.put("mail.imap.port", "143");
        properties.put("mail.imap.user", "user_name@alice.it");         
                
        properties.put("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.imap.starttls.required", "true");              
                
        properties.put("mail.debug", "true");
        properties.put("mail.debug.auth", "true");
        
        Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(account.getUsername(), account.getPassword());
            }
        };
        
        session = Session.getInstance(properties, auth);
        
        
        final Store store = session.getStore("imap");
        store.connect(account.getUsername(), account.getPassword());
        
        . . .
```

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.6.2
javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle]
DEBUG IMAP: closeFoldersOnStoreFailure
DEBUG IMAP: trying to connect to host "in.alice.it", port 143, isSSL false
OK IMAP4 Server
A0 CAPABILITY
CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UIDPLUS NAMESPACE QUOTA STARTTLS AUTH=PLAIN ID MOVE SORT SORT=DISPLAY THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=PARTICIPANTS THREAD=REFERENCES X-FIRSTLINE X-THREAD
A0 OK CAPABILITY completed
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAP: protocolConnect login, host=in.alice.it, user=user_name@alice.it, password=<non-null>
A1 AUTHENTICATE PLAIN
+
ABCDEF123==
A1 NO IMAP4 access not allowed
DEBUG IMAP: trying to connect to host "in.alice.it", port 143, isSSL false
OK IMAP4 Server
B0 CAPABILITY
CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UIDPLUS NAMESPACE QUOTA STARTTLS AUTH=PLAIN ID MOVE SORT SORT=DISPLAY THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=PARTICIPANTS THREAD=REFERENCES X-FIRSTLINE X-THREAD
B0 OK CAPABILITY completed
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAP: protocolConnect login, host=in.alice.it, user=user_name@alice.it, password=<non-null>
B1 AUTHENTICATE PLAIN
+
ABCDEF123==
B1 NO IMAP4 access not allowed
```

Comment: It looks to me like it didn’t actually do start TLS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IMAP server is denying this user access, see the part where it says `A1 NO IMAP4 access not allowed` in response to the login attempt. You can fix this only on the (IMAP) server-side.

Comment: It would appear that the provider refuses to consult emails outside its internet connection.